WooCommerce Coupon Code that is linked by a QR Code that can only be used once
For this project I would like to distribute unique QR Codes to users that redirect them to my WooCommerce site and offers a discount on a product. The problem I am facing is that I would like the discount to be a one-time use per QR code, so I cannot restrict the coupon by user or email address like I normally would.
My initial thought would be to redirect them with a url like so: www.MyWebsite.com/SpecialPromotion/{Guid}
and then when the Guid has been used for a coupon once it is no longer active, to prevent people from sharing the QR code with others. Custom PHP is a bit out of my wheelhouse. Are there any extensions that would provide this functionality, or is there a relatively simple solution with custom code?

If forced to do this, I would have a custom table that stored the codes and I would then record when they were used so they couldn't be used again, or delete them after they'd been used and if it's been deleted, then obviously the user can't use it.  I know there's been a ton of effort put into Smart and Dynamic coupons and codes for WooCommerce, so I'd put A LOT of effort into researching that first because to make what you're asking is going to require a bunch of complex coding. I've built something like this for 'invites' but it's not integrated with WooCommerce.
